# Suppressing the language select button iPhone

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

I'm working on an application now that contains an account register section.  One field with `secureTextEntry = NO` (for registering only).  The idea is this make registration faster and hopefully increases the number of signups. It's simple enough for me to just place a regular UITextField but if the user has any additional language keyboards then it's possible for the user to enter non-password friendly characters.  Unlike in when `secureTextEntry = YES`.

I know I can do

```
textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable
```

to get the text field to display the ASCII keyboard first, but the user will still have the keyboard switch button which will allow them to get to undesirable characters.

Is there a simple method for suppressing the international button or forcing ASCII only keyboard with no international button?

[EDIT]
Another perhaps better option might be to suppress multi byte keyboards or even to display the text in the case that `secureTextEntry = YES` any ideas here?

[EDIT AGAIN]
I've decided it's a really bad idea to suppress the international button as non-multibyte characters should all be allowed.

Comment: You asked and someone took the time to answer.  If this question is deleted, Olaf loses the answer and rep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at `-(BOOL) textField:(UITextField*)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString*)textEntered`.

If your users enters something that your password doesn't like then remove it. Just make sure they understand that a particular letter is not accepted. Otherwise users will look at the keyboard but not at the screen and assume because they have touched the button the character is entered into the password.

This might be easier than re-designing a whole keyboard.

Comment: I've played with this a bit but it's a bit odd to have the user click on a key and have nothing show up in the text field.  If a users keyboard doesn't have any ASCII characters then nothing would be able to be entered.

Comment: I see your point. On the other hand I wonder how strong you need your passwords to be. An all ASCII character password is rather insecure.

Comment: I suppose a better option might be to suppress multi byte keyboards or even to display the text in the case that secureTextEntry = YES .  It appears secureTextEntry = YES just suppresses multibyte.

Comment: I've been searching and thing and it appears there is no way to suppress the international option, no would it be wise to in general only way to really do this is to do what you've suggested and prevent some characters from being entered.  Thanks.